# OSDK application with DJI assistant 2 simulator

Tags: dji-sdk

I want to test my OSDK aplication and the DJI examples with the simulator of DJI Assistant 2 for the M600 Pro. Is it safe to keep the propellers during such test at the drone or do I need to detach them every time I'm testing the application?

I already searched a lot for this topis. I know, that it is mandatory to remove the props for some of the smaller DJI drones. Also the DJI chat told me only to detach the props of the M600 during firmware updates but could not say anything about the simulator use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am literally testing out the Matrice 100 in my room with the DJI Assistant 2 simulator as I write this. I think it is probably best to keep the propellers detached just for safety reasons.

If the cable connecting the M600 Pro to your computer running DJI Assistant 2 were to become attached, you would probably be okay even if you moved the controller joysticks because the drone would be in simulation mode and you would have to restart the aircraft in order to regain manual control of the motors.

But still, accidents happen...